Is there a Tikz or Circuitikz headphone jack connector diagram?
A Tikz or CircuiTikz headphone jack connector symbol like these here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29#/media/File:Phone_Jack_Symbols.svg
A headphone jack connector is widely used in circuit diagrams related to audio input-output but it is also an input connector easily available at low cost to connect sensors probes like pH sensor with up to 4 pins. Some phone jack connectors has internal switches that allow detection of the pin insertion. Although there is a large number of configurations used for phone jacks the characteristics of the symbols are quite distinctive including a ring pin, a v-notch tip and an arrow tip at 90 degrees representing internal switches. The PJ-306 (D-type configuration below) with 5 pins is one of the most widely used.

A typical usage circuit:

A didactic explanation of the usage of audio jack switches:
Understanding Audio Jack Switches and Schematics.

Please include an image in your question so that your question remains useful even if the link stops working.

No, there is no such a symbol --- or set of symbols. But you can undoubtedly build one... which one are you interested in? And yes, please, add the image to the post. You can also consider asking for a new component here: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/new/choose

The PJ-306 with 5 pins is the one mostly used as in the picture added above. I asked for a new component as suggested!(:-)

There are a lot of possible symbols. I will try to tackle something, but maybe the best thing is to draw your own. For example:
\documentclass[border=2.78pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,2) to[short, o-] ++(1,0) -- ++(-45:0.2) -- ++(45:0.2);
        \draw (0,1) to[short, o-] ++(.6,0) -- ++(45:0.2) -- ++(-45:0.2);
        \draw (0,0.5) to[short, o-] ++(1.8,0) rectangle ++(0.2,1.5);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}


Or your 5-ways one:
\documentclass[border=2.78pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,2) to[short, o-] ++(1.5,0) -- ++(-45:0.2) -- ++(45:0.2);
        \draw[-Triangle] (0,1.5) node[ocirc]{} -| ++(0.5,0.5);
        \draw[-Triangle] (0,1) node[ocirc]{} -| ++(0.5,-0.5);
        \draw (0,0.5) to[short, o-] ++(1,0) -- ++(45:0.2) -- ++(-45:0.2);
        \draw (0,0.0) to[short, o-] ++(2.3,0) rectangle ++(0.2,2);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}


Which could be easily put in a subcircuit...
